# Mysql Join Two Queries

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two queries:

```
SELECT opr, COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE field = 'YES' GROUP BY opr

SELECT opr, MAX(category) FROM table WHERE field = 'NO' GROUP BY opr
```

So basically in the first query I am getting the number of transactions a user makes. 
In the second query I am getting a category that all of those transactions fall under. I don't want to get all categories for each transaction they made, just the Max of the category field so that I have one entry per operator.

Until now, I have been catching both result sets in separate arrays and the looping through both arrays to get the complete opr->picks->category.

This doesn't always work it sometimes associates the wrong category to the wrong operator.

Is there a way to combine these two queries into one, so that I get the operator and picks, then the MAX(category)? The issue is that the conditions for each query are different on the field column.

Comment: With that fixed, I am sure you have the answer for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT opr, 
       COUNT(CASE WHEN field = 'YES' THEN 1 END) AS number_of_transactions,
       MAX(CASE WHEN field = 'NO' THEN category END) AS category
FROM table 
GROUP BY opr ;
```

Comment: Absolutely brilliant, thank you so much. Thanks to everyone who posted.

Comment: @ypercube seconds matter while posting answer :)

Answer (score 1):

The above logic can be attained in one query by using `CASE`

```
SELECT opr, COUNT(CASE WHEN `field` = 'YES' THEN opr END) as `count`, 
MAX(CASE WHEN `field` = 'NO' THEN category END) as `max`
FROM table   GROUP BY opr
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add it in:

```
SELECT opr,count(*), MAX(category) FROM table WHERE field = 'YES' GROUP BY opr
```

You might also be able to drop it from 2 queries to 1 with this:

```
SELECT opr,count(*), MAX(category), field FROM table GROUP BY opr, field
```

Answer (score 0):

even faster on the processor, use a sum bool:

```
select 
opr, 
sum(field='yes') as transactions, 
max(if(field='no',category, null)) as category
from table 
group by opr
```